# Image not overlapping second outer-div

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, top-to-bottom. I need an image to be on-top of both divs. I've got it working (with this code) in IE. But It simply fails on Chrome.

It appears to me that Chrome just ignores my manual `z-index` even though it says it doesn't in Dev Tools.

How can I have the image in outer-div 1 overlap outerdiv and inner-div 2?

http://jsfiddle.net/spikey/7zPuy/

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <p>Foo</p>
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Wiki_Makes_Video_logo.png" alt="Demonstration image. This image is in the public domain." id="image" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <p>Bar.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.outer
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;

    -webkit-transform: skewY(-3deg);

    background-color: lightgray;
}

.inner
{
    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;

    margin: 0 auto;

    -webkit-transform: skewY(3deg);

    background-color: gray;

    text-align: center;
}

#image
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;

    margin-top: 140px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `position`for z-index to work, like `position: relative`if you don't want any other effects.

In order to solve your problem you also need to make two top divs appear over the bottom, with z-index, like this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/7zPuy/4/)**

Answer (score 2):

specify `position:relative;` with respect to z-index

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `position: absolute` to use z-index. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zPuy/1/).

Comment: @Spike It turns out the Chrome doesn't like webkit-transform. If you disable it then the z-index works fine :-/
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/7zPuy/6/)

Comment: Yeah, I've always said Chrome sucks. I just haven't had any reason to like it.

Comment: Yeah agreed. One of the things I really hate about web design is conforming to all of the idiosyncracies of every browser you *decide* to support...